# firebase data retrieval - how to get data?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

so i have my database set up like this-

```
-classes
    -ksOYOlOg8xfvjOFFwRMWWVdsfNG3
        -CS4001
            -csFlrY0P6vf5HwIPEfKYipPEdtt2
                -firstName: "John"
                -lastName: "Smith"
```

I need to iterate through all the various first names and last names without knowing each user ID...

I have used this code -

```
var classes = db.ref("Classes/ksOYOlOg8xfvjOFFwRMWWVdsfNG3/CS4001");

 classes.on('value', function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
      var childData = childSnapshot.val();
      console.log(childData);
    });
  });
```

and the site is logging-

```
{FirstName: "John", LastName: "Smith"}
```

however I cannot access the value of firstName and lastname from childData like i can a regular JSON or anything, i have tried many things like converting to string, json but none seem to work

it seems like i might be doing this completely wrong so if anyone knows how to be able to just retrieve each first name and last name from under CS4001 without knowing the UID it is stored under it would be greatly appreciated.

it seems i am getting an object with all the key/value pairs but cannot access the data

why does this object that has the first name / last name, when i add toString to it, print out [Object object] when it should be a string? whats the point of the toString function then? so confused

Comment: You have at typo: your structure is *classes* and your code is trying to access *Classes*  - upper vs lower case 'c'

Comment: yea sorry that was typo on my part its not in my project ill fix it

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out myself-

```
cs4001.orderByChild('LastName').on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.key + " is " + snapshot.val().LastName + " " + snapshot.val().FirstName);
  });
```

Comment: Your answer has a a typo in it as well. The child node is lastName, not LastName.